# Microsoft Genalog installing issues

Tags: python, pandas, pip

i'm currently working on a project where i need to install Microsoft genalog in order to test some things.
i've tried to install it on a mac M1 and windows 10

When i try to install it in a venv with the command: `pip install genalog`
It return two kind of errors.

> ```
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python==4.2.0.34
> ```

on windows i cannot move from this error, while on mac if i run:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

and then i run again `pip install genalog` this time it returns the error:

> ```
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas==1.0.1
> ```

i've tried different venv, installing all the package from the requirements.txt but the same errors occurs.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? `pandas==1.0.1` requires `Python>=3.6.1.

Comment: On MAC: python 3.9.7
On Windows: python 3.9.4

Comment: Seems not related with opencv so I am removing the opencv tag.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `genalog` has been mis-packaged in that [it specifies an overly strict version of `opencv-contrib-python`](https://github.com/microsoft/genalog/blob/b8b9fbabdde5855e8bcc9db025e78cc619e15cd1/requirements.txt) (and other dependencies).

While the package itself should probably be fixed (I raised an issue for this: https://github.com/microsoft/genalog/issues/53), for starters you can try hand-installing ["close enough"](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#compatible-release) versions of the dependencies from that requirements file, followed by installing the project itself with `--no-deps`. (`pip` may warn you about wrong dependency versions, but carry on nevertheless and give running things a shot.)

```
pip install biopython~=1.76 numpy~=1.18.1 python-dotenv~=0.11.0 requests~=2.23.0 azure-core~=1.10.0 azure-common~=1.1.26 azure-storage-blob~=12.3.1 tqdm~=4.43.0 Jinja2~=2.11.1 WeasyPrint~=51 matplotlib~=3.2.1 scikit-image~=0.16.2 opencv-python~=4.2.0 pandas~=1.0.1 aiofiles~=0.5.0 aiohttp~=3.6.2
pip install --no-deps genalog
```

Naturally, be sure to do this in a virtualenv.

Comment: I've tried on my m1 but unfortunately  it seems not a working solution

Comment: Well, what happens with those instructions? (Also, on the M1, are you running an ARM build of Python, or an emulated Intel build?)

Comment: when i run it it gives me first error on `WeasyPrint~=51` , i change it in `weasyprint` and then it gives me error on `scikit-image`. i remove the version and gives me error on `opencv-python`. I remove also this version, then the error that i receive each time is different (even on the mac of my collegue). this time i received : `ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly`

the python version is: 3.9.7
I tried with rosetta terminal and even with the normal terminal

Comment: There are wheels for mac/arm64 for opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python. Which version of `pip` are you running? Can you try upgrading it (e.g. `python -m pip install -U pip setuptools wheel`) just to make sure this is not a pip bug?